# Ubuntu 20.10 is failling , all apps are not responding

Tags: 20.10

Ubuntu 20.10 is working badly in my notebook. All apps are frozen and throw `app is not responding ...` error messages. Speaker sound, headphone, camera and microphone aren't working, even after rebooting Ubuntu. All apps except Chrome are not responding.

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 
  Desktop: N/A Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: OMEN by HP Laptop 15-dh1xxx v: N/A 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: HP model: 8746 v: 04.30 serial: <filter> UEFI: AMI v: F.15 
  date: 09/15/2020 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 66.2 Wh condition: 66.2/69.0 Wh (96%) 
  model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 status: Full 
CPU:
  Info: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-10750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: N/A 
  L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 62399 
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/5000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 9: 801 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Device-2: Quanta HP Wide Vision HD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  bus ID: 1-5:3 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1920x1080 
  OpenGL: renderer: NV168 v: 4.3 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: sof-audio-pci bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU116 High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-50-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus ID: 00:14.3 
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 3c:00.0 
  IF: enp60s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.38 TiB used: 17.95 GiB (1.3%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Lenovo model: UMIS RPJTJ512MEE1OWX 
  size: 476.94 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10SPSX-60A6WT0 
  size: 931.51 GiB temp: 41 C 
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci 
  v: 3.0 bus ID: 00:17.0 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 412.24 GiB used: 17.92 GiB (4.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: 10.0 C gpu: nouveau temp: 40.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 337 Uptime: 18m Memory: 23.33 GiB used: 1.67 GiB (7.2%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 Packages: 2033 
  Shell: Bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.1.07
```

Comment: sorry , yes . i did

Comment: Did you look in /var/crash for crash reports and /var/log/syslog for error messages?

Comment: let me check it but the problem is when i try to do anything system frozen and appears " not responding" even terminal and i must wait long